# Trying to create team with owner using principal name, gives error "Failed to find users with user principal name" but user is owner of 365 account

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Request URL
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams`

Request Body

```
{
    "template@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')",
    "displayName": "Team22",
    "description": "My Sample Team’s Description",
    "members": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
            "roles": [
                "owner"
            ],
            "user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('vishalkumar@4vswmg.onmicrosoft.com')"
        }
    ]
}
```

Response Code 404

Response Preview

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "NotFound",
        "message": "Failed to find users with user principal name 'vishalkumar@4vswmg.onmicrosoft.com'",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-05-13T06:55:15",
            "request-id": "9df9a8fa-21cc-4455-b39f-ef1aca1d4b07",
            "client-request-id": "24d55bd6-3f77-b808-221e-3f1a7af7dd5a"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with user Id instead of user principal name?
In document for create teams graph API the user Id is mentioned instead of user principal name.
Ref doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-1

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT Yes it creates TEAM with MS Teams User UUID, but I want to create TEAM using email ID

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT In my business case I'll only have user emails not MS Teams UserID (UUID)

Comment: Using user principal name you can get the user id using following API.
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}
Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-1-standard-users-request

Comment: Could you please confirm is your issue resolved or are you still looking for any help?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT Thank You! Yes, It is resolved. Ref Doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-9-application-permissions-using-user-principal-name

Answer (score 0):

The following payload worked for me:
Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-9-application-permissions-using-user-principal-name

````
   "template@odata.bind":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')",
   "displayName":"My Sample Team",
   "description":"My Sample Team’s Description",
   "members":[
      {
         "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
         "roles":[
            "owner"
         ],
         "user@odata.bind":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('jacob@contoso.com')"
      }
   ]
}```

Keep in mind you can add only one owner at the time of Team creation using Graph API
````